# Ionic - Slide animation dont works on $http request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a factory that loads data from parameter url. When I use `$http.get()` ionic don´t runs the slide animation (nav router), but If I call `$state.change('newState')`without an $http call, the animation goes perfect.

As you can see in the html code I call the `$scope.navigate()` function to load the data in the `$scope.pageData` var and then load the view with all the data loaded.

If you think it is not the best way to do it, please tell me how can I accomplish this task.

My code:

```
var ayuda = angular.module('ayuda3cero', ['ionic'], function($interpolateProvider, $ionicConfigProvider){
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('<|');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('|>');
    $ionicConfigProvider.views.transition('platform');
})

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/')

  $stateProvider.state('home', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: 'home.html'
  })
  .state('ayudar', {
    url: '/ayudar',
    templateUrl: 'ayudar.html'
  })
  .state('recibir', {
    url: '/recibir',
    templateUrl: 'recibir.html'
  })
  .state('agradecimientos', {
    url: '/agradecimientos',
    templateUrl: 'agradecimientos.html'
  })
})

.factory('dataLoader', function($http) {
    return {
        get: function(url){
            return $http.get(url);
        },
        post: function(url){
            return $http.post(url);
        }
    }
})

ayuda.controller('AyudaController', ['$scope', '$ionicSideMenuDelegate', '$state', '$ionicPopup', '$window', '$http', 'dataLoader',
            function($scope, $ionicSideMenuDelegate, $state, $ionicPopup, $window, $http, dataLoader) {

  $scope.pageData = {total_nece: $window.ayudas, total_ayuda: $window.ayudados};

  $scope.navigate = function(state, url){
    $http({method: "GET", url: url}).then(function(data){
      $scope.pageData = data.dataArray;
      console.log($scope.pageDate);

    });

    dataLoader.get(url).then(function(response){
      $scope.pageData = response.data.dataArray;
      $state.go(state);
    });
  };
}]);
```

EDIT:

HTML CODE

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <link href="{{ URL::asset('plugins/ionic-modal-animations/animate.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{{ URL::asset('plugins/ionic-modal-animations/animate-styles.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <script type="text/javascript">
      var inicioUrl = '{{ route('wInicio') }}';
      var ayudarUrl = '{{ route('wAyudar') }}';
      var recibirUrl = '{{ route('wRecibir') }}';
      var agradecimientosUrl = '{{ route('wListaAgradecimientos') }}';
      var publicUrl = '{{ url('/') }}';
    </script>

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>



    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>

    <style>
    @font-face {
      font-family: BebasNeue;
      src: url({{URL::asset('fonts/BebasNeue_Regular.otf')}});
      font-weight: normal;
    }
    body{
      font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    }
    .scroll-content {
      background: url({{URL::asset('images/fondo.png')}});

    }
    .titular{
      font-size: 30px;
    }
    .container{
      background-color: transparent;
    }
    h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, h5 span{
      font-family: BebasNeue;
      text-align: center;
    }
    .textoAzul{
      color: #1e9dba;
    }
    .menu .scroll-content{
      background: #000;
    }

    #ayudaMenu .item, #ayudaMenu .item-complex .item-content, .item-radio .item-content{
      background: transparent;
      color: white;
      font-family: BebasNeue;
      letter-spacing: 0.8px;
    }
    </style>

    @yield('custom-css')
  </head>
  <body ng-app="ayuda3cero" ng-controller="AyudaController" style="background: #ffffff;">



    <ion-side-menus>

      <ion-pane ion-side-menu-content>
        <ion-nav-bar class="bar-dark">
          <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
            <button class="button" ng-click="toggleLeftSideMenu()">
              <i class="icon ion-navicon"></i>
            </button>
          </ion-nav-buttons>
          <ion-nav-title>
            <img src="{{URL::asset('images/cristo3cero.png')}}" style="height: 100%; width: auto;">
          </ion-nav-title>
          <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
            <button class="button" ng-click="navigate('https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?app_id=504928036346158&u={{urlencode(route(Request::route()->getName()))}}&redirect_uri={{urlencode(route(Request::route()->getName()))}}')" target="_blank">
              <i class="icon ion-social-facebook"></i>
            </button>
            <button class="button" ng-click="navigate('https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url={{urlencode(route(Request::route()->getName()))}}&text={{urlencode("Ayuda 3.0 La primera WEBApp de ayuda al prójimo")}}&via=cristo3cero')">
              <i class="icon ion-social-twitter"></i>
            </button>
          </ion-nav-buttons>
        </ion-nav-bar>
        <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
        <script id="ayudar.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-dark bar bar-header">
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content>
        <div class="padding">
          <div id="mapaPanel" class="padding" ng-show="geoAccepted">
            <div class="center">
            <img class="smallimg" ng-src="<|public|>/images/cristo3cero-necesitanayuda3cero.png" style="height: 100%; width: 90%; max-width: 400px;">
               </div>
            <p class="font2" style="text-align: center;">El siguiente mapa muestra persnas cercanas a ti que necesitan ayuda</p>
             <p class="font2" style="text-align: center;">Haz click en los iconos para ayudarles.</p>
            <div id="map" style="border: 2px double black;height: 70vh;"></div>
          </div>

            <div id="listaPanel" class="padding" ng-hide="geoAccepted">
              <h1>Gente cercana a ti que necesita ayuda</h1>
              <h2>Selecciona tu municipio y te mostraremos una lista de las personas que necesitan ayuda.</h2>

              <div class="item item-input-inset">
                <label class="item-input-wrapper">
                  <input type="text" name="Ciudad" id="Ciudad" placeholder="Nombre de la ciudad">
                </label>
                <input type="submit" value="Buscar" ng-click="submitBuscar()" class="button button-small">
              </div>

              <br/><br/>
              <div class="cristoQuote padding">
                <i class="icon ion-quote textoAzul"></i><br/>
                <p>Comienza a manifestarse la madurez cuando sentimos que nuestra preocupación es mayor por los demás que por nosotros.</p>
                <br/>
                <p style="text-align: right;" class="textoAzul">#cristo3cero</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </ion-content>
    </script>

        <ion-footer-bar align-title="left" class="bar-dark">
          <h1 class="title" style="text-align: center;">@yield('footerTitle')</h1>
        </ion-footer-bar>
      </ion-pane>

      <ion-side-menu side="left">
        <header class="bar bar-header bar-dark">
          <h1 class="title">Menú</h1>
        </header>
        <ion-content class="has-header" id="ayudaMenu">
          <ion-list>
            <ion-item nav-clear menu-close ng-click="navigate('home')">
              <i class="icon ion-home"></i> Inicio
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item nav-clear menu-close ng-click="navigate('ayudar')">
              <i class="icon ion-thumbsup"></i> Quiero ayudar
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item nav-clear menu-close ng-click="navigate('recibir')">
              <i class="icon ion-help-buoy"></i> Necesito Ayuda
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item nav-clear menu-close ng-click="navigate('agradecimientos')">
              <i class="icon ion-ribbon-a"></i> Agradecimientos
            </ion-item>
          </ion-list>
        </ion-content>
      </ion-side-menu>

    </ion-side-menus>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBsevGsO0q45WgM6xhpYzCPhRgSm618COw"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

As you can see I have Laravel Blade codes inside the HTML code for initial loading some images and routes. I had only put one of the templates for no set this code too long, it is enough for seeing the code.

Answer (score 1):

Incorrect return value in factory.

Try this:

```
get: function(url){
  return $http.get;
}
```

Perfect solution:

```
.factory('dataLoader', function($http, $q) {
    return {
        get: function(url){
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $http.get(url)
                .then( function(d) {
                    deferred.resolve( d.data );
                 });
            return deferred.promise;
        }        
    }
});
```

Call factory method: dataLoader.get(url).then( ... );

Comment: Thanks a lot, your code runs perfect, but still same issue. If I do `$http.get()...` directly from `$scope.navigate` runs perfect as well as if I do from the factory. The data load is perfect always. The problem is the slide animation of the view when I do `$state.go()`. No animation if I have done an http call.

Comment: Please attach your html source too.